# Add function to login wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add some code to the login process (when a external user logins in to my site).

I have searched a lot but cant find a way to add functionality to the login process. If possible i would like to add to it to functions.php

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function your_function( $user_login, $user ) {
// your code
}
add_action('wp_login', 'your_function', 10, 2);
```

[check the document.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login)

Comment: If this is the answer to your question (and I'm pretty sure it is) then please mark it as the accepted answer.